# Запуск слайдшоу

Tags: jquery, html, javascript

перебрал массу всего. за ссылку спасибо. то, что мне нужно оказалась называется слайдшоу. остановился вот на таком:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1251">

<script type="text/javascript">
NewImg = new Array ("image1.jpg","image2.jpg","image3.jpg","image4.jpg");
var ImgNum = 0; var ImgLength = NewImg.length - 1; var delay = 1000; var lock = false; var run;
function chgImg(direction) {
if (document.images) {ImgNum = ImgNum + direction;
if (ImgNum > ImgLength) { ImgNum = 0; }
if (ImgNum < 0) { ImgNum = ImgLength;}
document.slideshow.src = NewImg[ImgNum]; }
}
function auto() {
if      (lock == true)  { lock = false; window.clearInterval(run); }
else if (lock == false) { lock = true; run = setInterval("chgImg(1)", delay); }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<table id="table1">
<tr><td colspan="3"><img src="image1.jpg" name="slideshow"><br><br></td></tr>
<tr>
<td><a href="javascript:chgImg(-1)">    Back</a></td>
<td><a href="javascript:auto()">        Play / Stop</a></td>
<td><a href="javascript:chgImg(1)">     Next</a></td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

1. код смогу довести до оптимального для меня, но прошу помочь, немного подредактировать. как сделать запуск слайдшоу автоматически? (в данном коде нужно нажать кнопку)
2. как сделать кнопку, к имеющимся трем, что бы при нажатии перепрыгивала скажем на 3й слайд и останавливала слайдшоу?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Автозапуск

```
window.onload = function(){
    auto();
}
```

Переход к нужной

```
var goTo = function(num){  
    document.getElementsByTagName('img')[0].src = NewImg[num];  
    clearInterval(run);  
}
```

и

```
<a href="javascript:goTo(3)">3</a>
```

**Дополнено из комментария**.

И ещё пара моментов.

1)

```
var ImgNum = 0; var ImgLength = NewImg.length - 1; var delay = 1000;
```

равносильно

```
var ImgNum = 0, ImgLength = NewImg.length - 1, delay = 1000;
```

2)

```
setInterval("chgImg(1)", delay);
```

лучше задавать так

```
setInterval(function () {
    chgImg(1);
}, delay);
```

3)

```
<a href="javascript:chgImg(-1)"></a>
```

лучше навешивать событие из скрипта

```
<a id="qwe" href="#"></a>
```

и

```
window.onload = function () {
    document.getElementById('qwe').onclick = function () {
        chgImg(-1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Перенесено в ответ.

Answer (score 1):

На BODY поставь событие `onLoad="auto();"`.

Вроде бы как-то так должно быть.